# returning Completable after realm async transaction execution

Tags: android, rx-java2, realm-mobile-platform

i'm using realm 3.4 and rx java2. What i want to accomplish is to return a Completable after inserting data into realm.

```
public Completable insertSamplesRx(final List<Sample> sampleList) {
    realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            for(Sample s : sampleList) {
                realm.insertOrUpdate(sampleList);
            }
        }
    }, new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            Completable.complete();
        }
    }, new Realm.Transaction.OnError() {
        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable error) {
            Completable.error(error);
        }
    });
}
```

This code obviously doesn't compile because a return is missing. How i can return the completable result here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It is important to remember that Rx objects do not generally do anything until `subscribe` is called.

You should look into [`Completable.create`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Completable.html#create(io.reactivex.CompletableOnSubscribe)) to see how to convert an "action" into a Completable that can complete or cause an error.

Comment: Yes, i want to return a Completable for this purpose, such that whoever calls this method is in charge to subscribe to the completable event, i'll take a look into the create as well. The "problem" here i think is that the realm onsuccess and on error callbacks return void, therefore i suppose is needed something like flatmap. But i'm quite new to these comncept so maybe i'm wrong. Waiting for some rx guru :D

Answer (score 0):

Hope this can help you

```
public Completable updateChangeSancions(int resultId,int inspetionId, int sanction) {
    return Completable.fromAction(() -> {
        try (Realm r = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
            r.executeTransaction(realm -> {
                RealmResults<InspeccionDetalle> detalles = realm.where(Inspection.class)
                        .equalTo("resultId", 1)
                        .equalTo("inspetionId", resultId)
                        .findAll();

                for (InspeccionDetalle i : detalles) {
                    i.setPersonalSancios(sanction);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: When uses Completable.create not return subscribe

Answer (score 0):

We can make Kotlin extension function for Realm

```
fun Realm.completableTransaction(
    transactionBlock: (realm: Realm) -> Unit
): Completable {
    return Completable.create { completable ->
        this.executeTransactionAsync(
            Realm.Transaction { transactionRealm: Realm -> transactionBlock(transactionRealm) },
            Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess { completable.onComplete() },
            Realm.Transaction.OnError { t: Throwable -> completable.onError(t) }
        )
    }
}
```

and use something like this

```
fun save(foo: RealmFoo): Completable {
    return realm.completableTransaction { _realm->
       foo.name = "bar" 
       _realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(fooList)
    }
}
```

this will only work when subscribed

```
save(foo)
.subscribe({
    // saved
},{
    // error
})
```

Answer (score -1):

For whom it may concern, the solution working is using from action, which throws an exception in case something is wrong, and forces the completable to trigger the error.

```
 public Completable insertSamples(final List<Sample> sampleList) {
    return  Completable.fromAction(new Action() {
        @Override
        public void run() throws Exception {
            realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
            realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
                @Override
                public void execute(Realm realm) {
                    realm.insertOrUpdate(sampleList);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

It's important to remark that an explicit call to the realm instance is needed for not incurring in

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Realm access from incorrect thread. Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they were created.

Comment: Combining `fromAction` and anything async will result in the completable completing before the action is actually performed, since no exception gets thrown.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote: i tested the use case and if the realm transaction fails the observer recieves an onError correctly, onSuccess otherwise.